# In a group of X people, what is the probability that there is at least one person with a birthday on every one of the 365 days?

Tags: probability, combinations

My attempt at a solution was to calculate all possible combinations that *would not* satisfy the condition of every date being represented:

S = Σ ((365 choose n) * n^X)

n=364->1

i.e. there are (365 choose 364) ways to only populate 364 dates, and each of those possibilities has 364^X total possible states, there are (365 choose 155) ways to only populate 155 dates, and each of those possibilities has 155^X total possible states, etc.

Then subtract unsatisfactory possible states from total possible states, and divide the whole thing by total possible states:

(365^X - S) / (365^X)

My proposed solution doesn’t return 0 for population less than 365, which a solution should. I’ll be a little disappointed in mathematics if the answer to this requires a “if X <365 then 0, else…”!

Comment: This is the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: The exact answer is $\dfrac{365! \, S(X,365)}{365^X}$ where $S(X,365)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind (one property is $S(n,k)=0$ when $n < k$). But this can be an effort to calculate, so you may prefer an approximation

Comment: @TonyK, that Wikipedia page is painfully vague. How is anyone to know what “expected” means? >50%, >99%, >99.99%?

Comment: "expected value" is a well defined concept in probability.   See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) for instance.

Comment: When I look at similar problems, having eliminated both Inclusion-Exclusion and the direct approach as being unwieldy, I naturally think of recursion.  Here, that is immediately seen to be pointless because of the comment of @Henry.  If an elegant recursion approach was feasible, that would imply an elegant simplification to the corresponding Stirling number, which represents the exact answer.  Since Stirling numbers are known to have no elegant simplifications, it has to be game over.

Comment: Unfortunately, your method is not correct.  The problem is that there is no easy way to know if your set of birthdays fills up your preferred subset.  When you speak of $155^X$ it is perfectly possible that every one of your $X$ has the same birthday (one of the special $155$), a possibility you count over and over again.  Of course, in extreme cases (where the population is very large compared to the subset), the probability of getting everything in the subset is reasonably high, so in this situation you might hope to get a decent approximation.

Comment: I see you are right. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @lulu - I did not read slothish1's comment that way but instead the same answer for $15$ days and $100$ people was about $0.9849$ can be found by recursion or  [using Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=15%21+*+StirlingS2%28100%2C15%29+%2F+15%5E100)